# how to calculate sum of each row in 2d array and print the max sum. c language

Tags: c

i have assignment to write 2d array and calculate the sum of each row and compare with the sum of each row and print the maximum sum i have

here is my work:

```
 #define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
 #include <stdio.h>
 #define N 3
 void  insertmat (int arr[][N]) //function to fill the 2d array
 {
int i=0,j=0;
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
   {
    for(j=0;j<N;j++)
     scanf("%d",&arr[i][j]);
   }
}


 int main()

{
int arr[N][N],maxsum,i=0,j=0,sum1=0,sum2=0,sum3=0;


insertmat (arr);



    for (j = 0; j < N; ++j)
    {
        sum1 = sum1 + arr[j][i] ;
    }

if(sum1>sum2)
{
    maxsum=sum1;
}
else 
    maxsum=sum2;
if(sum3>maxsum)
    maxsum=sum2;

printf("the max sum is %d\n",maxsum);
}
```

i know how to calculate each row and print every sum, but i need to save the sum of each row in variable so i can compare each row have the maximum sum and then print the max sum

Comment: Fix the indentation and stop pressing the enter key. One blank line will suffice

Comment: You missing one `for loop` with `i` before `for (j = 0; j < N; ++j)` in `main()`

Comment: but if i add  the for loop with i then the compiler will calculate the sum of all rows right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this function to get Max of all the rows :

```
int GetMaxOFRow(int arr[][N],int N)
{
    int row_sum = 0;
    int row_max = -1;
    for(int i =0 ;i<N;i++)
    {
        row_sum = 0;
        for (j = 0; j < N; ++j)
        {
            row_sum +=  arr[i][j] ;
        }
        if(row_max < row_sum)
        {
            row_max = row_sum;
        }
    }
    return row_max;
}
```